# Как проверить, включена ли у пользователя Вк двухфакторная аутентификация? (питон)

Tags: python, tkinter, вконтакте, авторизация

Всем здравствуйте.
Я делаю небольшой апп на питоновском `tkinter`-e для работы с Вк (библиотека `vk_api`, но если нужно будет, поставлю новую). Мне нужно, чтобы, если у пользователя включена двухфакторная аутентификация, появилось окно для ввода кода и прошла соответствующая проверка, а если нет, то сразу дальнейшая работа. Сейчас у меня, после нажатия кнопки, выполняется такая функция:

```
def task(event):
    user_log,user_pass=log_ent.get(),pasw_ent.get()
    frame1.pack_forget()
    
    def two_auth():
         key=auth_ent.get()
         rem=False
         return(key,rem)
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=user_log, password=user_pass)
    try:
        vk_session.auth()

    except vk_api.exceptions.AuthError:
        # создаются виджеты для проверки кода - кнопка 'check', окно для ввода 'auth_ent',label
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=user_log, password=user_pass, auth_handler=two_auth)
        def test(event):
            vk_session.auth()
            vk = vk_session.get_api()
            print(vk.wall.post(message='Hello world!'))
            frame2.pack_forget()
            
        check.bind('<ButtonRelease>',test)
```

Проблема в том, что, когда в блоке 'test' проводится `vk_session.auth()`, он присылает новый код , и старый, естественно, не работает. Нужно как-то по другому провести проверку на "двух-факторность" в начале, но я не могу придумать, как.  Я пробовала `account.getInfo`, но для него нужно уже пройти авторизацию. Нет ли какой-нибудь другой функции? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

C помощью библиотеки request пытаешься распарсить страничку юзера с пост запросом владельца страницы (в vk_api вроде есть такой метод) далее смотреть итог реквеста и там будет либо страница с дввухфакторкой и кодом, либо со страничкой новостей пользователя и там уже как-то обработать. С данной библиотекой не работал, но чисто предположил, может помог как-нибудь :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, извините за столь замедленную реакцию)  Если можно, объясните, пожалуйста, что значит "распарсить", т.к. гугл, когда я стала искать, выдал мне только процесс прочитывания компьютером кода. Спасибо